# Wo sind sie hin gegangen?

Tags: grammaticality

Ich weiß, dass man oft in der Alltagssprache so sagt:

`Wo wollt ihr hin?`

`Wo kommt ihr her?`

Das ist aber nicht hundertprotzentig grammatikalisch, wie man weiß.

Ich frage mich daran, ob man so sagt, wenn es ein bestimmtes Wort am Ende des Satzes gibt.
Wie würde man sagen?

`Wo sind sie hin gegangen?`

`Wo sind sie gegangen hin?`

`Wohin sind sie gegangen?`

Comment: Wieso sagst du es ist "nicht grammatikalisch", wenn du gleichzeitig meinst, dass man es in der Alltagssprache sagt? Wenn man es systematisch sagt, ist es grammatikalisch. Ob es für alle stilistischen Niveaus passt, ist eine andere Frage.

Comment: @Alazon: auch wenn ich Dir in diesem speziellen Falle rechtgebe: nicht alles, was man "in der Alltagssprache" sagt, ist deshalb auch grammatikalisch: "es macht keinen Sinn", "daran zu vergessen", "wegen dem" ständigen Wiederholen dieser Unformen denselben auch nur die mindeste Korrektheit zuzugestehen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Wo sind sie gegangen hin" geht genauso wenig wie "Sie sind gegangen dorthin". Richtungsangaben stehen normalerweise eng vor dem Prädikat. Ins Nachfeld (nach der Endposition des Prädikats) können nur größere Satzteile, vor allem Nebensätze. Aber "hin" ist zu leicht dafür.

Nur in alten Gedichten wird man Abfolgen wie "Wo sind sie gegangen hin" finden. Aber da gelten andere Maßstäbe, Metrum und Reim sind dann wichtiger:

"Ach, ich ruf in Angst und Schmerzen:

Wo bist du gegangen hin?

Keine Ruh' ist in dem Herzen,

bis ich wieder bei dir bin."

-- Don't try this at home :) Das ist für die Alltagssprache nicht möglich (sondern ist anscheinend ein altes Kirchenlied: https://books.google.de/books?id=EodFAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA291&ots=46ck_5eyU4&dq=%22du%20gegangen%20hin%22&hl=de&pg=PA291#v=onepage&q=%22du%20gegangen%20hin%22&f=false )

Comment: In der Alltagssprache sollte ich also „Wohin sind sie gegangen?“ benutzen, oder?

Comment: "Wo sind sie hingegangen" ist auch ok.